# Ignore post by meta value in the main query

Tags: wp-query, loop

I use this function to insert at the beginning of the loop two post at my convenience (with meta key and value)

```
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'insert_post_wpse_96347', 10, 2 );
function insert_post_wpse_96347( $posts, \WP_Query $q ) {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    if ( $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_home() && 0 == get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {

        $args = [
            'meta_key'         => 'caja', 
            'meta_value'       => ['uno','dos'], 
            'post__not_in'     => get_option( "sticky_posts" ), 
            'posts_per_page'   => '2',
            'suppress_filters' => true
        ];

        $p2insert = new WP_Query($args);
        $insert_at = 0;
        if ( !empty( $p2insert->posts ) ) {
            array_splice( $posts, $insert_at, 0, $p2insert->posts );
        }
    }
  return $posts;
}
```

But these posts still appear in the loop, they would have to hide to not look twice.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to put two specific posts at the front of your query results/loop? Also do any of the other posts in the loop have meta_key `caja` and any values?

Comment: @userabuser Yes, it does. But these two post are still displayed in the rest of the loop and may confuse the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following alternative way:

- Remove the two posts we select via our custom query from the main query via the `pre_get_posts` action
- Return the two posts on top of page one via the `the_posts` filter

Lets look at possible code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    if (    $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page     
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
    ) {
        // Set our query args and run our query to get the required post ID's
        $args = [
            'meta_key'         => 'caja', 
            'meta_value'       => ['uno','dos'], 
            'posts_per_page'   => '2',
            'fields'           => 'ids', // Get only post ID's
        ];      
        $ids = get_posts( $args );

        // Make sure we have ID's, if not, bail
        if ( !$ids )
            return;

        // We have id's, lets remove them from the main query
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $ids );

        // Lets add the two posts in front on page one
        if ( $q->is_paged() )
            return;

        add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, $q ) use ( $args )
        {
            if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
                return $posts;

            // Lets run our query to get the posts to add
            $args['fields'] = 'all';
            $posts_to_add   = get_posts( $args );

            $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
            if ( $stickies ) {
                $sticky_count = count( $stickies );
                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_count, 0, $posts_to_add );

                return $posts;
            }

            // Add these two posts in front
            $posts = array_merge( $posts_to_add, $posts );

            return $posts;
        }, 10, 2 );
    }
});
```

This should replace the current code that you have posted in your question

Comment: Copy and paste and it works! But using `array_merge` put the two post before the post sticky. Before `array_splice` had chosen the option. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: I've solved so with [this code](http://pastebin.com/NiJwGJpg). What do you think?

Comment: Good Morning. Glad the first set of code worked, even though just halfway. We can do what you did in your link much faster which will also safe on resources and db calls. I have updated my code, so be sure to check it out

Comment: Thanks Pieter, it works! I've just changed some parameters to `get_post` to respect an order `'meta_value' => [1,2], 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'asc'`

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. The code is always there for you to modify at will, just as long as the biger picture is what you are looking for. ;-) Enjoy nd good luck on your project

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

**NOTE: make sure to add any extra conditional logic you need for your usecase, such as a check for `is_home()` and the value for `get_query_var( 'paged' )`. I have intentionally left those out just for brevity.**

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_meta_query( $query ) {

    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;


    $meta_key = 'caja'; //meta_key to query

    $query->set( 
        'orderby', 
        array(
            'meta_value' => 'DESC',
            'date'       => 'DESC'
        ) 
    );

    $query->set( 
        'meta_query', 
        array(
            array(
                'key'     => $meta_key,
                'value'   => 'IGNORE THIS VALUE', //this just needs to be something random
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        )
    );

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_where_meta_query' );

}   

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_meta_query', 1 );


function custom_where_meta_query( $where = '' ){

    global $wpdb;

    $meta_key    = 'caja'; //meta_key
    $meta_values = array('uno', 'dos'); //meta_values

    $sql = "'" . implode( "', '", array_map( 'esc_sql', $meta_values ) ) . "'";

    $where .= $wpdb->prepare( 
        " OR (( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = %s AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value IN ( {$sql} ) ))", 
        $meta_key
    );

    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_where_meta_query' );

    return $where;

}
```

The first callback function on `pre_get_posts` will initiate `WP_Meta_Query` which builds the neccessary SQL that we then filter in the second callback function.

The results are first ordered by `meta_value DESC` then by `date DESC`. This will group the two matched posts for the meta key `caja` at the top and the remaining posts will be sorted by date thereafter.

This avoids you having to re-query the database for two specific posts you want, then splice the result set and finally purge the result set of the duplicates.